# How to get header values in canActivate method

Tags: angular

My application is getting called by a third-party app. The third-party application set some header values before calling my application.

Based on Route.canActivate property the respective call will be landed in ***canActivate*** method.

Is it possible to get the header value set by a third-party application in ***canActivate***?

Regards

Comment: Do you mean header in http response?

Comment: Yes...I want to read the header sent by the third-party application.

Comment: How is a third party app ‘calling’ your application..?

Comment: Using Browser agent...They will have a link to our application...On click of it, they will open a new window and request will land our application

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at angular documentation

[Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: Guess, this one for HttpClient...In the above, we are not sending the request. As mentioned, the third-party application invokes our application (For example, it will invoke the login response page).

Comment: Okay, than you need to get the data from the third-party application. I think you cant get the header if you do not handle the request by yourself.

Comment: What about getting values from the cookie set by third-party application